# Keep user's input in textbox after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created a register form and an error handler which handles the errors that the user makes while registering. After submitting the form, possible errors appear to the user. I am trying to use javascript in order to keep the data that the user has entered in the textfields, even after he has submitted the form so he hasn't got to reenter the data again.
For the form I have used HTML and CSS. 
What confuses me is what function am I going to use and how will I apply it in every element of the form!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use ajax, so that form is also submitted and data is also not lost.

Comment: There's not enough info in your question to say for sure. If the data's not private you can save it in a cookie. Or pass the values in the url as GET variables. If you are not using server side scripting, you can set the data in the onload event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 2):

I found this, I hope it helps!  I'm assuming you are running this on IIS or something similar, otherwise, PHP has a very friendly way of letting you do this ala the $_POST variable.

aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function setSessionVariable(valueToSetTo)
{
 __doPostBack('SetSessionVariable', valueToSetTo);
}
// -->
</script>
```

aspx.cs file:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 // Insure that the __doPostBack() JavaScript method is created...
 this.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);

 if ( this.IsPostBack )
 {
  string eventTarget = (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == null) ? string.Empty :    this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
  string eventArgument = (this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

  if ( eventTarget == "SetSessionVariable" )
  {
   Session["someSessionKey"] = eventArgument;
  }
 }
}
```

Then later you will have to have one of the form elements read similar to

Then you will have to Javascript a onpageload or something similar and then have document.FormName.element.ElementName = Session Variable (or var set from dissecting the POST data).

My apologies, I'm much more familiar with PHP - I hope this helps you find the answer you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you very much, although (hope this will not sound very dumb-I am kind of beginner) could you tell me what a .cs file includes?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with ASP in about any way, so, I'm not sure.  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5897/Behind-the-scenes-of-ASPX-files) <-- Says that the .cs of the aspx file does the heavy lifting whereas the aspx file itself does the styles and design work.
I would recommend following the idea submitted by @anuj-arora as AJAX will do a lot of the work of keeping your data on the client side with submission parts that more or less work in the background, without "re-loading" the page.
There are several AJAX Frameworks out there, best wishes!